# JavaFX program does not start due to "GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline"

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx, openjfx

I just wanted to run a basic JavaFX HelloWorld program on Ubuntu 16.10.
Therefore, I add the jar `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-opendjk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar` to my buildpath.

Yet, it compiles but crashes on start up. I use `-Dprism.verbose=true` as flag to get the following output:

```
Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw 
Using java-based Pisces rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/share/java/openjfx/jre/lib/amd64/libprism_es2.so
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1827)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFullPath(NativeLibLoader.java:201)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:94)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:39)
    at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.lambda$static$0(ES2Pipeline.java:68)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.<clinit>(ES2Pipeline.java:50)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:187)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
*** Fallback to Prism SW pipeline
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/share/java/openjfx/jre/lib/amd64/libprism_sw.so
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1827)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFullPath(NativeLibLoader.java:201)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:94)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:39)
    at com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline.lambda$static$0(SWPipeline.java:42)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline.<clinit>(SWPipeline.java:41)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:187)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:221)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:205)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    ... 5 more
```

When I look at the folder `/usr/share/java/openjfx/jre/lib/` there is no subfolder `amd64`, and consequently, it cannot find the library `/usr/share/java/openjfx/jre/lib/amd64/libprism_es2.so`.

What can I do to solve this? Do I have to install this library separately (besides running `sudo apt-get install openjfx`)?

Comment: Have you installed `openjfx`? Did it install the dependency `libopenjfx-jni`? What is the output of `update-alternatives --display java`?

Comment: @sillyfly: Yes, I installed `openjfx`. I just checked, `libopenjfx-jni` is also installed (`libopenjfx-jni is already the newest version (8u102-b14-1).`).
The ouput of `update-alternatives --display java` is:

`java - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
  link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
  link java is /usr/bin/java
  slave java.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java - priority 1081
  slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz`

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I am not sure... I think that I completely uninstalled opdenjdk and openjfx and reinstalled it, but I am not sure...

Answer (score 1):

I met a simlilar problem on linux mint. Finally I solved it with VM arg `-Dprism.order=sw,j2d`.
For me it only happened on Jetbrains IDEA, if I run `mvn javafx:run` from system shell, it works fine. but fails on the terminal window of IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download openjfx from https://openjfx.io
2. Unpack it
3. Create directory `/usr/share/java/openjfx/jre/lib/amd64/` - if doesn't exist
4. Copy all of the `.so` files from unpacked openjfx to new directory

Answer (score 0):

Replace your JDK with the proper version of [JDK FX](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?package=jdk). It worked for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to run a .jar file, java might not be seeing the module path containing certain javaFX libraries due to your javaFX installation being in a different location than it expects. This was an issue for me on my arch linux installation, as openjdk-jfx is installed to /usr/lib/jvm/java-XX-openjfx/. To fix this you can do one of two things - you can add a global variable to your /etc/environment to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH like so:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/.../java-XX-openjfx/lib
```

or you can set the module path when running the .jar, specifying the modules that you would need:

```
java -jar --module-path /.../java-XX-openjfx/lib/ --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml whatever.jar
```