# JavaFx Jar file doesn't run on linux (run well on windows)

Tags: java, linux, maven, javafx

I try to launch a javaFx .jar file, build with maven on a linux device but it doesnt work.

Error logs:

```
root@myDevice:~/Bureau# java -Djavafx.verbose=true -Dprism.verbose=true -jar myApp-0.3.0.jar
Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw 
Using Double Precision Marlin Rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:333)
    at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
*** Fallback to Prism SW pipeline
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
WARNING: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /root/Bureau/libprism_sw.so
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no prism_sw in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2670)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:806)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1909)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:163)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:53)
    at com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline.lambda$static$0(SWPipeline.java:42)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline.<clinit>(SWPipeline.java:41)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:333)
    at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:244)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:260)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:272)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$la
```

I use OpenJDK 13 and open JFX13

I have Already installed java and java fx on my linux device
(apt-get install openjfx for java fx)

I also tried to install GTK 3.0 to solve the issue.

There is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>myArtId</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.0</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>13</javafx.version>
        <javafx.platform>linux</javafx.platform>
        <mainClass>nextBack.Main</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-base -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-graphics -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I use the jar-with-dependencies build on the linux device.

The package generated work fine on widows.

Command use for launching the app: java -jar myPackage.jar.

Comment: have you checked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573488/javafx-program-does-not-start-due-to-graphicspipeline-createpipeline-failed-for

Comment: Are you creating a “fat jar”?  If so, that .jar file won’t contain the native libraries required by JavaFX.

Comment: Yes I create a jar with all the dependency inside.

Comment: @sudipn thanks for the linnk i will try to uninstall opdenjdk and openjfx and reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally downgrade my java project to a older JDK version(8) with javaFx inclued, that fix the issue, but there are probably better way to solve it.